# Loading not advertised layers into opengeo SDK app

Tags: boundless-suite

I`ve made several apps using OpenGeo suite SDK but so far never needed to keep layers from being exposed in the capabilities. Now I´ll like to "hide" some of them but still being able to load them. I taught that the solution was to set the layers as not advertised but if I do that the app will not load those layers!! 
As far as I understand I should be able to call a layer that is not advertised!!
Using geoexplorer and saving the map I can do the same with no problems….  Any idea what may be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use lazy loading (which bypasses GetCapabilities, so provide title and bbox properties in the layer's config), see also:

[https://github.com/boundlessgeo/gxp/blob/master/src/script/plugins/WMSSource.js#L172:L186](https://github.com/boundlessgeo/gxp/blob/master/src/script/plugins/WMSSource.js#L172%3aL186)

Comment: Thx... I knew that I was missing something...